# How is road completion determined?

Tags: death-stranding

I've been rebuilding roads since getting to Lake Knot City, and noticed that I seem to be the only one completing them. I built the first segment, and when I came back to the game a few days later, I noticed that other segments had appeared. However, since then, no other roads have appeared, although some paving machines have had partial materials loaded into them.

To me, this indicates that road completion (past the first few segments?) isn't actually shared between players, since it seems very unlikely that no other players would have completed later roads. Furthermore, the materials in the paving stations aren't always in units of 40 or 50, and as far as I know, that's the most granular you can get with the materials you have in-game.

Are materials or road completion actually shared with other online players?

Comment: This is pretty much my experience as well. I completed the first segment, and suddenly the next couple of segments were completed as well. Since then, I feel like I'm the only one building roads.

Comment: My guess is that they leave road completion to you because there's a stat about number of Road Sections Restored (see Bridge Links menu, Structures tab).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience:

- 2 out of 40 total road sections were completed in my game by someone else - I don't know if they were actually completed by other players or not. This looks like tutorial thing to me.
- When building roads in areas with Chiral Network coverage they always had some resources added to construction, I only had to add some part to finish them. Looks like this works like any other structures from players.
- When building roads in areas without Chiral Network - 0 resources at start, I had to provide 100% resources to build them.
- Even after completing all roads I regularly see messages like "Player X added resources to auto-paver near Y" or similar wording.

To summarize I think that progress is shared but only to some extent (that explain why sometime you can see resources amount not dividable by 40 or 50), you have to finish most of the roads yourself. First few segments are exceptions, you won't have any roads finished next to Mountain Knot City.

Comment: Interestingly, I had also the same experience, 2 or 3 roads max from other people, but one of them was indeed near Mountain Knot City